# VueJS & Laravel: A bunch of empty rows when using v-for on a table

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to bind a json array to a table. Therefor I'm using `v-for` on a `<tr>` tag.

```
<tr v-for="file in files">
    <td>@{{ file.name }}</td>
    <td>@{{ file.hash }}</td>
    <td>@{{ file.size }}</td>
    <td>@{{ file.download_count }}</td>
    <td>@{{ file.id }}</td>
</tr>
```

The `file` is bound through vue, which loads from a JSON.

```
<script>
    var url = '{{ route('getAllFiles') }}';
    new Vue({
        el: '#fileTable',

        data: {
            files: null
        },

        created: function(){
            this.fetchData();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData: function(){
                var self = this;
                $.get(url, function(data){
                    self.files = data;
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The JSON looks like this: http://pastebin.com/tNy7A4Yw so that should be correct.
The `console.log(data)` I've used inside of `fetchData()` looks exactly like the API Output, so I don't see any error.

Comment: Do you getting any console error ? Try to set property `dataType: 'json'` to `$.get` method.
Edit: Sorry, I see now you said there are no console errors.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should set the initial `files` data as an empty array not null because `v-for` will render a list based on an array. read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) .

Comment: exacly what you should do, can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

So using the Vue Dev Tools I saw that my JSON Output was escaped in the `files` array.

I used a `$.parseJSON` like so:

```
new Vue({
        el: '#fileTable',

        data: {
            files: [],
            filesAreReady: false
        },

        created: function(){
            this.fetchData();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData: function(){
                var self = this;
                $.get(url, function(data){
                self.files = $.parseJSON(data);
                self.filesAreReady = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now it works.